# How do I control the camera in Kite Photography?

Tags: remote, wireless, aerial-photography

I saw an older post on the site that mentioned [Kite Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6061/good-diy-photography-projects-for-an-old-digital-camera). I find that very interesting, and I want to try it.

I have a couple of old compact cameras that I wouldn't mind putting them at risk.
(Ideally I would like to try it with on old Olympus mju 300.)

What tips and information do you have to share?

I cannot really figure out how to have the compact camera take pictures while in the air, and away from my hands. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: If you want to know more about Kite Aerial photography, there is [a very informative forum](http://arch.ced.berkeley.edu/kap/discuss/) that has helped me alot in the past to take [my first KAP picturs](http://www.flickr.com/photos/biogeek/tags/kiteaerialphotography/show/)

Comment: @BioGeek This forum looks very interesting! I will have a good look at it... I like the pictures that you have posted on flickr!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

that's an interesting question!

The first thing you need to consider I guess is the type of kite you wish to use; i.e. will you be using a single line kite, or a 2-4 line controllable kite? I'd recommend using a large-ish single line kite which will allow you to more easily use a really long line which will help to get the camera to a better altitude.  Probably go for [a delta kite](http://www.spiritofair.co.uk/delta_conyne.htm) or a [parafoil/flowform kite](http://www.activetoys.co.uk/shop/kites/single-line-parafoils-soft-kites/flowform-single-line-kites-363128.html) of around 1-2 square metres.

The second thing to think about is how to activate the shutter.  The easiest way would be to simply use the time delay having the camera mounted about half way along the kite line (as shown in Fig. 78 of the image below).  If you want a more elaborate way to activate the shutter (which also enables you to have the camera mounted closer to the kite and hence higher) you could consider using radio control gear from an old car or plane; you'd basically need to mount a servo with a cam on the output shaft mounted on top of the camera (this is shown in the photo below). I'm doing exactly this to get aerial shots from a radio controlled aeroplane!

[[Images from the book "[Kites and other wind machines](http://books.google.com/books?id=a5IgqOYZzEwC&dq=editions:a5IgqOYZzEwC)" by Andre Thiebault removed due to copyright infringement]]

My own remotely operated shutter release, soon to be attached to an RC plane!

[image: Servo operated shutter release]

**Edit**
After initial tests, I can confirm that I **do not** recommend attaching a camera to a remote controlled aircraft :-(

(See below image)

[image]

Comment: @mdresser: Just curious where you got the graphic from? It's very informative, but I'm suspicious that photo-SE may not have the rights to use it... Unless the rights are yours to give, it needs to be a link to the source...

Comment: Looks like it's from a 30-year-old book. http://books.google.com/books?id=a5IgqOYZzEwC&dq=editions:a5IgqOYZzEwC Unfortunately, we can't just include that, as informative and interesting as it is. @mdresser, could you please summarize instead? Sorry, but, y'know, following the law and so on.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the offending images.

Comment: I notice that there's ten copies of this book available on Amazon for 99¢. Seems like a good investment if one has any interest in this! http://www.amazon.com/Kites-Other-Machines-Andre-Thiebault/dp/0806954647

Comment: fair enough. updated answer to recommend AGAINST the use of a model aeroplane for aerial photos...

Comment: Well, I did try out a small kite I had bought a couple of months ago (two line kite!). After 5 minutes of flying... I abandoned the idea of even trying to attach my old compact camera... I now need to look into two things! A new **one line kite** and a way to make a **custom intervalometer** for my compact camera!!!
@mdresser: After your test I don't think I am willing to risk any other (more expensive) equipment!!  Sorry about the result of your test...

Comment: LOL, nice update! I can confirm that it doesn't always end up that way though. The important thing is to learn to fly safely FIRST, then mount cameras. IMO, you want at least a full summer of flying under your belt before attempting this - unless you use a GoPro, which survives crashes very nicely.

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet would be to find a compact camera that can support time-lapse photography (natively or via [custom ROM](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK)).  When you start to get into pricier equipment and more sophisticated control mechanisms, you really need to be looking at a different platform (ie, a plane or helicopter) because of the added weight and the risk of damage should you lose control of the kite.

Comment: I'd actually say that, for the case of a single line kite at least, there'd be much less likelihood of loosing control of it than there would of loosing control of an RC plane or helicopter.

Comment: I must suffer from some sort of Charlie Brown syndrome; my experience (as an amateur, mind you) has quite a few more rough landings than smooth ones.  I'm sure a more skilled flier would be more comfortable putting expensive equipment on board.

Comment: .. not cool

Comment: @Leonidas The idea of CHDK that your answers mention sounds really good! But... Even though I have 3 or 4 old compact cameras resting in my drawers, none of them is a Canon! I wish Olympus would have done something similar!

Comment: One popular choice with time-lapse support would be the GoPro cameras: http://gopro.com/product-comparison-hd-hero2-hd-hero-cameras/

Answer (score 5):

Concerning how the camera keeps taking pictures while on the kite, you might have read [my answer to the question what one can use the intervalometer-script of the CHDK for Canon-cameras](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/intervalometer-ideas/7873#7873) for.

If you own an older Canon compact, [look at the list here](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this is not quite what you have in mind, but you could consider taking some video before moving on to still photos. I bought a low-quality digital video camera off eBay for ~10USD. It's about the size of my thumb, and weighs just a few grams. It's a good way to experiment, you can see what kind of views you would get without having to consider how to release the shutter, and if it all goes terribly wrong, you're only out 10 bucks. (I came to this plan after breaking a basic Canon digital camera (~50USD on eBay) with a rough landing.)

Some other tips:

1. Use a single-line kite. A relatively small (<2 metre span) single-line delta, rokkaku or foil can most likely lift a compact camera.
2. You need to consider how you'll suspend the camera from the kite line. Attaching a camera directly to the kite frame does not work. A Picavet suspension is fairly simple and effective.
3. If the wind isn't right, don't force it. Put the kite away and try another day.
4. Don't expect brilliant results on your first outing. It takes some practice.

Comment: I especially like you 3rd suggestion!